# Bulk creation of email account in QMail

Tags: linux, redhat, email

Is there any command in QMail server that I can create bulk email accounts.

OS : RedHat Linux Enterprises
Email Server : QMail
CP : Plesk 9

Comment: Virtual or non-virtual?

Comment: virtual user on virtual domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have done it.

I creaed list of email in a text file.
Used the mail.sh command to process the file and created the email address in bulk.

Comment: http://www.encodez.com/book/migrating-email-from-cpanel-to-plesk-exim-to-qmail-1.html

Comment: The above mentioned guide was moved to a new domain, hence I am posting the updated URL https://uppercase.dev/blog/migrating-email-from-cpanel-to-plesk-exim-to-qmail-1